# British term for "Homeland security"

Tags: phrase-requests, british-english

Homeland security, an umbrella term for counter-terrorism, counter-espionage and the like has a distinctly American feel. Here I mean the concept, rather than the specific "Department for Homeland Security".

Is there a term with the same meaning that's used in the UK?

Comment: I don't think we have an equivalent term in the UK.

Comment: See this article: [Does Homeland Security Exist Outside the United States?](https://www.hsaj.org/articles/69): "Homeland security is a uniquely American concept." (3rd result on searching 'UK "homeland security"').

Comment: @TrevorD I don't agree with that article. The concept exists in the UK, even if it isn't organised in the same way.

Comment: Britain does have "the security services" which is a *huge* umbrella encompassing MI5, MI6 and GCHQ as well as (potentially) the police and other bodies such as [UKVI](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/uk-visas-and-immigration). The term might even include the SAS and SBS, although it's unlikely to include the regular armed forces.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, that's quite good, but I'm trying more for the concept of defence against threats rather than the organisation(s).

Comment: In the cited article, read the 2 paras. beginning "A case in point is the United Kingdom." - and search for "UK" throughout the article.  They refer to, amongst other things, "counterterrorism strategy ... but it is not entirely equivalent to homeland security both because ...".  Yes, the *concept* of 'Homeland Security' may exist - but that doesn't mean that we have a specific name for it.

Comment: MI5 that conducts* internal intelligence* is a "domestic security" [intelligence] agency.

Comment: I believe the UK equivalent is the UKBA (UK Border Agency). However, this whole issue is rather differently viewed in Britain, perhaps because of the scale. There are 200 million entries + exits through UK ports and airports annually. This is over three times Britain's population. It would be like the USA having a billion comings and goings in a year. America retains a notion of "Homeland" - whilst London is an international city.

Comment: No-one has mentioned "national security", which I had thought would be one of the better possibilities. Thoughts?

Comment: @WS2 - this isn't correct at all. Homeland security is more than border, it includes police, intelligence, etc.

Comment: @Graffito And MI6 (formerly the "Secret Intelligence Service (SIS)") is a "foreign intelligence" agency. See [www.sis.gov.uk](https://www.sis.gov.uk/) and [www.britannica.com/topic/MI6](https://www.britannica.com/topic/MI6).

Comment: @WS2 [UKBA was closed in 2013](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/uk-border-agency). It's now UKVI (see my link earlier)

Comment: @Gremlin I don't think "national security" in the UK equates to US "Homeland Security" anymore than any of the other suggested terms. See [National security and intelligence](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/national-security) and [National Security Secretariat](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/national-security/about). There are also the "National Security Council" and the "Joint Intelligence Committee" (see first link).  These all encompass different but no doubt overlapping areas. cont'd ...

Comment: ... cont'd Hence the expression "national security" is vague and has no *clear* or *specific* meaning. As I understand it, they have no direct responsibility for border security - which thus differs from the US Homeland Security.  The simple answer to your original Q. *"Is there a term with the same meaning [as 'Homeland Security'] that's used in the UK?"* is **No, there isn't!**  All the UK terms have different scopes & implications from the US term.

Comment: It's funny that people think **homeland** security sounds American.  As an older American, when I first heard this recent coinage it sounded distinctly unAmerican because "homeland" wasn't a term typically used in the US.  It actually sounded more like a Russian term because it had a long history of use there.  For that matter, I moved to Washington DC around the time of the cold war and was shocked to discover that the biggest pharmacy chain was People's Drugs.  Maybe it was started by a Mr.. People, but it took a while for the "Russian" flavor to not seem out of place in the US capital.

Comment: @fixer1234 Maybe it's generational, but to me, *homeland* is distinctly American. The Old World has *motherlands* (Russia par exemple) and *fatherlands* (Germany par exemple), but [only in America (or possibly Canada)](http://www.simpsonsworld.com/video/275196995796) have we a homeland, because the national identity is not defined by bloodlines.

Answer (score 1):

The UK phrase that most closely resembles Homeland Security is **[Civil Defence](http://www.civildefence.co.uk)**.

The term covers rather more than Homeland Security, covering protection of the civilian population in times of war as well as counterterrorism, intelligence and other protection. The term is most associated with the Cold War era, when it covered nuclear attack alerts and shelters, as well as emergency provision for continuation of government.

Comment: My understanding of UK Civil Defence is that it is internal defense by trained *civilians*. That is **very** difference from the US Homeland Security, which is a huge *professional* organisation covering law enforcement, border control, and much more.

Comment: From the site you linked, the UK concept of civil defence is largely indistinguishable from the US concept of civil defense, which is about civilian reaction to a military or terrorist attack, and only one component of homeland security.

Comment: Didn't *Civil Defence* emerge from the wartime *Home Guard* - i.e. "Dad's Army". Perhaps that's the answer to the OP's question - "Dad's Army"!

Comment: @WS2, No the Civil Defence Service was created in 1935, five years before the Local Defence Volunteers (who later were called the Home Guard) were raised.